# rxjs how to listen to state change in a component

Tags: angular, ngrx

Versions

```
"@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^8.5.1",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^8.5.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^8.5.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.5.0",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.8"
```

I'm trying to listen and update the state in one of my components. I'm not sure how to do that correctly. I've tried

```
 this.ganttControls$ = this.store.select((state) => state.GanttControls);    

  //and

 this.ganttControls$ = this.store.pipe(
      select((state) => state.GanttControls)      
 );`
```

Here is the full implementation.

Actions

```
export const LOAD_GANTT_CONTROLS = "LOAD_GANTT_CONTROLS";
export const LOAD_GANTT_CONTROLS_SUCCESS = "LOAD_GANTT_CONTROLS_SUCCESS";

export class LoadGanttControlsAction{
    readonly type = LOAD_GANTT_CONTROLS;
    constructor(){}
}

export class LoadGanttControlsSuccessAction{
    readonly type = LOAD_GANTT_CONTROLS_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: GanttControls){}
}

export type Action = LoadGanttControlsAction | LoadGanttControlsSuccessAction;
```

Effects

```
export class GanttEffects{
    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private ganttService: GanttService){

    }

    @Effect() loadGanttControls$ = this.actions$.pipe(            
        ofType(ganttActions.LOAD_GANTT_CONTROLS),
        switchMap(() => this.ganttService.getGanttControls()

        ), 
        map((gControls) => (new ganttActions.LoadGanttControlsSuccessAction(gControls)))       
    );
}
```

State

```
export class GanttState{

    GanttControls: GanttControls = {
        ProjectTree: [],
        TaskTypes: []    
    };
} 

export function getInitialState(){
    return GanttState;
}
```

reducer

```
export function ganttReducer(state, action: ganttActions.Action){

    switch(action.type){
        case ganttActions.LOAD_GANTT_CONTROLS_SUCCESS:{
            return action.payload; //this line of code is being returned as expected.
        }
        default:{
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Gantt Service that gets the data

```
@Injectable()
export class GanttService{
    ganttControls: Observable<GanttControls>;

    constructor(private http: HttpService){        
    }

    public getGanttControls(): Observable<GanttControls>{        
        return this.http.get<GanttControls>('GanttFilter/GetGanttControls');
    }

}
```

in my component I have

```
    private ganttControls$: Observable<GanttControls>;

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
      private http: HttpService,
      private store: Store<GanttState>){

    }

       ngOnInit(){    
          this.ganttControls$ = this.store.pipe(
            select((state) => state.GanttControls)      
          );
        }

        public showFilter(){

          const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GanttFilter, {
            data: {filterControls : this.ganttControls$,
                    projectTreeConfig: {
                      hasAllCheckBox: true,
                      hasFilter: true,
                      hasCollapseExpand: true,
                      decoupleChildFromParent: false,
                      maxHeight: 500
                   },
                    projectTreeData: []},
            minWidth: '25vw',
            maxWidth: '90vw',
            minHeight: '50vh',
            maxHeight: '90vh'
          });
        }
```

When I check `this.ganttControls$` it's `undefined`

Both are registred in my app.module

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ganttStore: ganttReducer}),
EffectsModule.forRoot([GanttEffects])
```

Comment: Change your selection in to this : `this.ganttControls$ = this.store. select((state) => state.GanttControls)` Piping without requesting or subscribing is similar tor sending message to universe.

Comment: @Eldar would you be able to show how to correctly subscribe to that?

Comment: like this `this.store.select((state) => state.GanttControls).subscribe(s=> console.log(s));`

Answer (score 1):

I think this part looks wrong:

```
export class GanttState{

    GanttControls: GanttControls = {
        ProjectTree: [],
        TaskTypes: []    
    };
} 

export function getInitialState(){
    return GanttState;
}

export function ganttReducer(state, action: ganttActions.Action){
```

- The state is usually an interface
- You have a `getInitialState()`, but where are you calling it?
- with `return GanttState` you are returning a class?!

In my experience it should look more like this:

```
export interface GanttState {
    ganttControls: GanttControls;
}

export const initialState: GanttState ={
    ganttControls: {
        ProjectTree: [],
        TaskTypes: []    
    };
}  

export function ganttReducer(state: GanttState = initialState, action: ganttActions.Action){
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue with this line of code

```
this.ganttControls$ = this.store.select((state) => state.GanttControls);
```

was

`state.GanttControls`

I registered the reducer as

```
`StoreModule.forRoot({ganttStore: ganttReducer})`//I named it ganttStore
```

so I changed it to

```
this.store.select((state) => state.ganttStore);
```